# Raw ReactJS update properties

Tags: reactjs

I am using React to render some components needed to my web app and I have a timer with a play and a stop button. I am retrieve all of my time records from a get request and I want to rerender my component each time It changes, how can I do that?

I have everything working but with a simple setInterval to a function that calls this.forceUpdate() but that gives me the warning of:

> Warning: forceUpdate(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called forceUpdate() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the TimerBox component.

My component:

```
var TimerBox = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'TimerBox',

    updateTime: function () {
      getTime();
      this.forceUpdate();
      this.props.records = allRecords(); // get all time records
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
      setInterval(this.updateTime, 1000); // set interval to each second
    },

    render: function () {
      this.props.records = allRecords();
      return (
        React.createElement('div', { className: 'main-timer-box' },
          React.createElement('div', { className: 'timer-box' }, hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes and ' + seconds + ' seconds',
            React.createElement(ControlButton, null)),
          React.createElement('hr', null)
        )
      );
    }
  });
```

I am new to reactjs and I started using react without jsx, babel or webpack and I don't wan't to change the entire code, for now.

What I simply want is to know I can I declare a property and then make the property call a rerender on each time it changes value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update component state and it will automatically re-render component. Furthermore,  you have to clear timeout in `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method to make sure that `setState` is called only if component hasn't been unmounted.

```
 updateTime: function () {
      getTime();
      this.setState({
         records: yourRecordsData
      })
  }
  componentDidMount: function () {
      this.myTimer = setInterval(this.updateTime, 1000); // set interval to each second
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function () {
      clearInterval(this.myTimer)
  },
```

Now you can use state data in render functions like this: `this.state.records`.

Please note that React components are re-rendered when their state has been updated or when their parent has been re-rendered. You should never set component own props - you can only set props on child components. And generally you shouldn't use `forceUpdate` (and to be honest you will almost never need it). Check react [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) for more details and explanation why `forceUpdate` should be avoided.

Comment: That worked to update my component, thank you. But I now I have the same warning for the setState "... Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. ..." seems that the problem is calling the updateTime function

Comment: This because `setState` is called on timeout and when it's actually called your component has been unmounted. To avoid this you have to clear timeout in `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method to make sure that `setState` is called only if component hasn't been unmounted

Comment: Please see updated answer or use @finalfreq solution :)

Comment: Thank you, just accepted your answer that full solves my problem!

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you have a `setInterval` that has no notion of when the component has unmounted from the DOM. So once the component does unmount, the `setInterval` function fires off anyways and tries to update the state of the unmounted component which causes this problem.

To resolve that warning you just need to do:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
     this.interval =  setInterval(this.updateTime, 1000); // set interval to each second
    },

componentWillUnmount: function() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

what this does is set `this.interval` to the timer id of the interval and then using the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method we make sure we clear the timer that way the code isn't being executed after the component has unmounted.

Comment: That really solved my problem, thank you for your explanation and help, I was dealing with this for a long time! Although your answer helped me on solving my prolbem I need to make Bartek Fryzowicz the correct answer just to be fair because my question was about how to update properties without having to call forceUpdate(). Thank you one more time.

Comment: No problem! Glad it got you taken care of!